# Unable to view detail of an Object, if rendered via a @Factory method

Tags: seam

I have the following code in my entity query class, which I use to display a List objects. The objects do get displayed properly when I use the @Factory method name ("users") to iterate through all members in a rich:dataTable. But when I click on particular user to go the detail page, the following gets tacked on as a page parameter `(e.g. &dataModelSelection=_user:users[0])`which causes the page to not show the detail information, but if I remove this query parameter it seems to work fine. What could be possibly going wrong here?

```
@Name("userList")
public class UserList extends EntityQuery<User> {

    @DataModel(scope = ScopeType.PAGE)
    private List<User> users;

    @Factory("users")
    public List<User> getUsersByOrg() {

}
```

Note: If I comment out the line containing the @DataModel annotation, the above defined parameter is not defined and I am able to view user details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@DataModel annotation allows Seam to wrap some java.util.* collections such as List, Set and so on... JSF UIData components (rich:dataTable, for instance) needs a special collection wrapper whose base class is [javax.faces.DataModel](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17824_01/dsc_docs/docs/jscreator/apis/jsf/javax/faces/model/DataModel.html). **It supports row selection made by user** It explains why you see

```
dataModelSelection=_user:users[0]
```

So if you want to capture the selected user, you should use @DataModelSelection

```
@DataModelSelection
@Out(required=false)
private User selectedUser;
```

You can use h:commandLink to throw the backed action

```
<rich:datTable value="#{users}" var="_user">
    <h:column>
        <f:facet name="header">Action</f:facet>
        <h:commandLink action="#{userHome.view}" value="View"/>
    </h:column>
</richTable>
```